# How not to display commas at the start and the end of the list

Tags: java, tostring

I have a toString() method. How do I get it to print [A,B,C,D] instead of [,A,B,C,D,]

```
  public String toString()
  {
    String result = "[";

    if (numItems > 0)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < queueArray.length && queueArray[i] != null; i++)
      {
          result+= queueArray[i].toString() + ",";
      }    
      result += "]";
    }
    else
    {
      result = "[ ]";
    } 
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: As an aside, The output is incorrect according to the code - it will be [A,B,C,D,] (without the starting comma)

Answer (score 3):

Use a `StringJoiner`:

```
public String toString() {
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(","); // Use commas to attach

    if (numItems > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < queueArray.length && queueArray[i] != null; i++) {
            sj.add(queueArray[i].toString()); // Loop through & attach
        }
        sj.add("]");
    } else {
        sj.add("[ ]");
    }

    return sj.toString();
}
```

Here is another sample program, so as to clarify how it works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // You pass in the "joiner" string into the StringJoiner's constructor 
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("/"); // in this case, use slashes 
    // The strings to be attached
    String[] strings = new String[]{"Hello", "World", "!"};

    for (String str : strings)
        sj.add(str); // Attach

    System.out.println(sj.toString()); // Print the content of the StringJoiner
}
```

And the output is:

```
Hello/World/! // No slash in the end
```

Comment: Please note this is only available in Java 1.8 - for other versions, `StringBuilder` and for loop manipulation is imo better

Comment: You are right. But imho, this Java class is the most adequate for such tasks.

Answer (score 2):

```
public String toString() {
    return Arrays.stream(queueArray)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    //check whether its last item or not, to skip the appending comma at the end
    if(i==queueArray.length-1)
      result+= queueArray[i].toString();
    else
      result+= queueArray[i].toString() + ",";
```

OR

Simply,

```
Arrays.toString(queueArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < queueArray.length && queueArray[i] != null; i++)
{
      result+= queueArray[i].toString() + ",";
}
result = result.Substring(0,result.length() - 1);
```

Just add the above code line after the for loop and you are good to go

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some context to your answer; code-only answers are not very welcome. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate from i=0 to array length-2 to concatenate string with coma. At last element than you do neet to concat it with coma.

```
for(int i=0; i<queueArray.length; i++) {
    result += queueArray[i].toString;
    if (i != queueArray.length-1) {
       result += ",";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String toString() {
    String result = "[";
    if (numItems > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < queueArray.length && queueArray[i] != null; i++) {
            if(i!=0) result += ",";
            result+= queueArray[i].toString();
        }
        result += "]";
    }
    else {
        result = "[ ]";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use one line with `String.join`

```
String result = String.format("[%s]", String.join(",", queueArray));
```